# Antlr4 arithmetics representation

Tags: antlr4

I am parsing a SQL like language and I need to be able to handle this kind of expressions (for example only):

```
SELECT number_of_children - number_of_cars
```

this should be arithmetic subtraction of two columns.

```
SELECT child-name
```

this should be a column name 'child-name'

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you should have 4 tokens: `SELECT` `number_of_children` `-` `number_of_cars`.
In the second case you should only have two: `SELECT` `child-name`.

This can be achieved by carefully choosing your lexer rules:

```
SELECT: 'SELECT';
OP_SUB: '-';
ID:     [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*;
WS:     [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

These rules will yield `SELECT` `ID` `OP_SUB` `ID` in the first case and `SELECT` `ID` in the second one.

Comment: `ID` would now also match `child-----------`. I would go for something like this: `ID : [a-zA-Z](-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*;`

Comment: @Bart indeed but this wouldn't allow `abc--def`. Maybe `[a-zA-Z]('-'+ [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*` would do the trick, but it's up to the asker to define the language rules.